# Is there a way I can autowire a bean in my route without using the .bean keyword in Camel?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, javabeans, autowired

Lets say for example, I have the following route:

```
          from(.....)
          .choice()
          .when(condition1)
          .bean(Class1.class,"method1")
          .when(condition2)
           .bean(Class1.class,"method2")
          .otherwise()
          .bean(Class1.class,"method3")
          .end();
```

Is there a way I can autowire Class1 to use all the methods instead of using the .bean function in camel. If you know any other efficient method. Please do let me know. Hope to hear from you soon.

Thanks,
Gautham

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have a few other options...

- can use the bean component to reference a spring bean

  ```
  from("direct:hello").to("bean:bye");
  ```
- can use the beanRef() API to reference a spring bean

  ```
  from("direct:start").beanRef("beanName", "methodName");
  ```
- can use the annotation to inject and bean() API to reference the bean

  ```
  @Autowired
  Private MyService myService;
  ...
  from("direct://start").bean(myservice, "process");
  ```

Comment: I had used the second method as you suggested. But my team lead wants me to get rid of the .bean method alotogether and autowire instead. Is it possible to do so ?.

Comment: not sure what you mean to just 'autowire'...you have to use some Camel component/API to bind it to the route...otherwise, you can just use a Processor and delegate to the bean